# -bash: /Users/myname/.bash_profile: Permission denied

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal

I installed rvm (ruby version manager) and it was success, but I got

> WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it, to do
>   that add the following line to '/Users/myname/.bash_profile': source
>   ~/.profile

I am new to developing, terminals and all that jazz! But better late than never?!

I entered into terminal:

```
'/Users/myname/.bash_profile'
```

and got back the following line

```
-bash: /Users/myname/.bash_profile: Permission denied
myname-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$
```

And that is where I am stuck! I need vrm for Drupal (Omega development) and want to make sure that everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You just need to follow what it told you (refer to the warning).

Comment: try `sudo gedit /Users/myname/.bash_profile`

Comment: You might want to add a RVM tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Enter the `.bash_profile` file by running this in your terminal:

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

If you still get permission denied, run `sudo` before the `vim` command

`sudo vim ~/.bash_profile`

From there , press `insert` button . then add the text `source ~/.profile` to `.bash_profile`and press `esc` and then hit `:x` on your keyboard to save and close the file. Opening a new terminal window should remove the error.

Comment: You missed a few steps in describing how to use `vim` (entering and leaving insert mode). I love `vim`, but expecting someone with little familiarity with a command line to use it to edit a file is a bit much.

Comment: Thanks, Bobby. Had to google a bit around your answer. So, if it helps someone else: after opening the bash_profile (in vim) type "i" (without quotes) and you'll see message -INSERT- at the bottom of your screen. Then - type your line (source ~/.profile) and save it by hitting the esc button and then typing :w and finally enter. Close and reopen the Terminal. That did the trick for me!!!

Comment: Thanks @Booby and@Zel. My situation was a little bit different, my .bash_profile is readonly, when i hit ":wq", it showed error :"readonly, add ! to override" (i don't remember it exactly). So I added ":wq!", then my file became editable, and it not shows error anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Entering a filename will try to execute it. Instead, you want to edit it.

Open TextEdit (or your favorite editor) and open the file `/Users/myname/.bash_profile` in it.

You can do this entirely through the UI, but if you want, you can start an editor from the terminal:

```
open -a TextEdit /Users/myname/.bash_profile
```

You can then add the line `source ~/.profile` to the file and save it.

Close the terminal and open it again to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice, but got the warning 'You don’t own the file “.bash_profile” and don’t have permission to write to it.' I tried the same thing with the sudo (I know it doesn't make sense, but...) in front of open, but no joy again.

Comment: Thank you! @that_other_guy - found your answer the most helpful

Answer (score 1):

In my issue when I try with ssh on server, I get this error :

`-bash: /home/user/.bash_logout: Permission denied`

for resolved your user home directory must has a execute permission.

```
chmod +x <user_home_directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must relogin next. If you add .profile

```
export PATH+=:$HOME/bin
```

without .bash_profile as I do all time you'll insert ~/bin search dir not the end of PATH and in middle. So .profile call before local profile formed and some others system dirs will be added after. It's bad so priority for you home binaries will higher then some system one. And may change undesired behavior with same names. So you need to add PATH in .bash_profile, not to .profile   It's guarantee to add your home bin dir at the end of PATH. But don't delete ~/.profile  at all. It's need to add some other data. This file call once at first login and .bash_profile  call every time when second login  with su without -l and then return back. If don't bother You will get two home bin dirs in PATH, next tree and so on. It's not well. So you must correct like that:

```
p=:$HOME/bin && test `expr $PATH : '.*'"$p"` -gt 0 || export PATH+=$p || true
```

It's grantee that home bin dir will add only one independent how many times you login after change effective user with su and then return back.
true at end better write so if on some unpredictable reasons error occurs in 
command export PATH+=$p(sometimes such occurs) your profile load stops and you can't login at all. It's grantee that this line will run with any error generate.